# Should Java classes created by JAXB have logic code

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB to load an XML configuration file to a Java object (ConfigurationDTO). Is it good practice to add some logic code on the this Java object (ConfigurationDTO) or I should create a different java object with this logic code (ie Configuration). When I say logic code I mean some checks/constraints that the configuration file should have. Should the java class 'ConfigurationDTO' contain only getters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is why do you need that constraints? Are you going to use your object not only for marshalling/unmarshalling? If so it is bad idea. The rule of thumb is not to spread DTO objects among all levels of an application. If you follow this rule you'll not need to have additional constraints in your DTO.

The JAXB standard provides you with ability to validate an object during marshal and unmarshal time. It means that if your XML schema requires nonempty field but the corresponding java object has null value then marshal will fail. And vise versa.

Here is quote from [the JAXB documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/arch.html)

> Validation is the process of verifying that an XML document meets all the constraints expressed in the schema. JAXB 1.0 provided validation at unmarshal time and also enabled on-demand validation on a JAXB content tree. JAXB 2.0 only allows validation at unmarshal and marshal time. A web service processing model is to be lax in reading in data and strict on writing it out. To meet that model, validation was added to marshal time so users could confirm that they did not invalidate an XML document when modifying the document in JAXB form.

Such approach has its own drawbacks (if you spread the DTO among the application you'll lost control on it) but the advantages are more valuable.